# What is the best way to check the wires in your house?

Tags: electrical

Wires wear down eventually. This presumably can pose a fire hazard. But there are so many wires in a house and many of them are not easily accessible.

In order to maintain as safe a house as possible,

1. How can I check all the wires in my house?
2. How often should this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Modern copper wire does not wear down nor erode. At least not for a millennia of time. If your house wire and electric system was installed by a state licensed contractor than you don't need to worry. If you're not sure who installed the electric system and feel that there may be a potential problem, than you would be wise to call a local electrician and have him or her check and repair any issues. If you want edit your question with more detail and specifics (flickering lights, breakers shutting off regularly, breaker panel under- rated, etc.?) you may get a better answer.

Comment: Copper wire doesn't wear out, but insulation does break down and can become brittle over time - which is especially a problem when there is any movement or vibration of the wires which can make the insulation flake off, exposing bare wire.

Answer (score 3):

Household wire does not wear out (or down.) In the vast majority of cases where wire insulation is attacked by rodents (which appears to be your actual concern, or as close as your actual concern gets to something that does happen), nothing much happens, despite it being disturbing when found. They usually gnaw off one face of the insulation, and leave the exposed conductors not touching each other. Decades pass, someone renovates, it's found and replaced.

The obvious primary step there is rodent control.

In new construction or renovation, you can choose what's colloquially referred to (a long way from Illinois by electricians that have never worked there) as "Chicago code" (which may or may not be congruent with actual Chicago code) and put all wires in metal - metal boxes, armored flex cables, EMT or better metallic conduit. "Gnaw-proof" wiring. It costs a bit more, so it's not common in residential wiring.

In an existing house installation, changing the breakers over to AFCI breakers should protect against actual arcing in the hidden spaces where rodents can gnaw and you can't possibly inspect the wires. They may also drive you mad with nuisance trips from using brush-type motors (vacuum cleaners, etc), but that's part of that territory.

Where you have exposed wiring, sure, look at it once in a while - but 90% of the wire in any house is typically invisible from the time that it's installed until a major renovation results in the walls being ripped open or removed. If it's properly installed copper wire, fires started by the wiring are VERY, VERY Rare. Recall that the "electrical code" in the USA is, in fact, published by an organization primarily concerned with preventing fires.

Answer (score 2):

As was said, copper wire shouldn't "wear out" unless it's being flexed repeatedly.

On the other hand, if your house has *aluminum* wiring (which was briefly popular), that is known to be prone to connections loosening over time, and may want to be monitored or replaced.

Comment: What about animals chewing through it though? We had a phone line that was chewed through by an animal of some sort for example. This was another concern I had apart from wires simply wearing out. The line ran outside the house however, so that may be a completely different scenario. The inside portion was untouched.

Comment: Possible, but (a) uncommon and (b) really, really difficult/expensive to check for unless you're doing a gut-renovation on the building. Not usually something folks worry about unless they have reason to do so.

Comment: If you're really worried about degrading wires, afci breakers can detect arcing from failing wires and shut down the circuit.